# How to make the liquid to flow in a circle forming a swirling bubble

Tags: materials, fluid-simulation, animation-nodes, simulation-nodes

I tried to make it as natural as the gif, but I still feel like I'm not good enough. The liquid I expressed is not three-dimensional, so please help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: OK I will, thank you

Comment: I might be missing here something, why are there tags "fluid-simulation", "animation-nodes" and "simulation-nodes" under this question? To me this looks like an animated material, nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this node setup, plug a stretched *Noise Texture* into a mix between a glossy *Principled BSDF* shader and a *Transparent* one, add a bit of bump for small details:

[image]

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot!!

Comment: I've edited, use the Texture Coordinate "object" output